# Redirect 401 Error in React Redux Actions File

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm trying to redirect the user if the server responds with a 401 Unauthorized response based on the user authentication backend I've established. Currently I'm sending a request to the server to check if the user matches with the item I'm checking against. IF they don't match, a 401 Unauthorized response is returned. But I cannot properly redirect them in my .catch(err) statement in my actions file.

I've tried several different solutions, stackoverflow searches, google searches, tutorials, and still cannot get the results I want. I've also tried installing different packages to no avail.

Here is my actions file. The .catch(err) is where I'd like to redirect the user to if a 401 error comes back.

```js
// Get Single Score
export const getScore = (id, history) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setScoreLoading());
    axios
        .get(`score/${id}`)
        .then(res => 
            dispatch({
                type: GET_SCORE,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch(err => 
            dispatch({
                type: SCORE_NOT_FOUND,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
            history.push('/not-authorized')
        );
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is your arrow function . you use => directly that will return your dispatch but never touch your history.push

.catch(err => {dispatch({
                type: SCORE_NOT_FOUND,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
            return history.push('/not-authorized')
        )}
Hope this help.
Btw use history.replace is better in this case in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed my code to reflect your changes, but now I'm getting an error that says: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I'm already importing { push } from 'react-router-dom', but it's grayed out meaning it's obviously not getting called properly??

Comment: Did you import history?

Comment: iqbal125, I'm not entirely familiar with how to do that. I pass history in through the getScore(), but I'm not importing it from some other file or resource? I haven't had to do that with successful .then() things when I want to redirect? It's just not working on the error version?

Comment: Buckyx55. This is just your action. When you use your action inside your component. With react router you have acces to props.history so you should pass history into your function. You got undefined because you didnt pass history into your parameters. Do you have an other code when u use this action ?